# Redirect from web page in one project to another project using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I've 2 projects, Project 1 contains `Login.aspx` and Project 2 contains `Welcome.aspx`. How can I redirect from Login.aspx to Welcome.aspx after logging in? 
I've used

```
window.location.href = "Welcome.aspx?username=" + returnValue;
```

It's not working. Please help.

Comment: window.location.href = "http://secondproject.com/Welcome.aspx?username=" + returnValue;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can do it this way. I didnt tried this. But it may be usefull.

```
<a href="Http://localhost/<name of the second project page"> click here </a>
```

or

```
 window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/Welcome.aspx?username=" + returnValue;
```

- In addition if you would like to run two web sites simultaneously it is better to configure the project to use the local IIS instead of webdev.
- Use iis name for each project for redirect

  [image]

Here ImageUpload and Image are 2 different project. Using this name it can be connected.

EG:-

To redirect from `Login.aspx` in `Image` project to `Welcome.aspx` in `ImageUpload` project

```
window.location.href = "http://ImageUpload/Welcome.aspx?
```

Comment: U r welcome. Vote up my answer when ur reputation reach above 15.